# Confidence Intervals Sample Size

Tags: statistics

A city planner wishes to determine the proportion of residents who own their home. He wishes to be 95% confident that the estimate is within 2 percentage points of the true percentage. 
(a) How large should the sample size be? A previous estimate indicated that 40% of the residents own their home
(b) How large should the sample size be if no previous estimate is available.

so far i got 1-alpha=.95 
where i got alpha to be .05
alpha/2 = .025
so Z.025=1.96

1.96sqrt(pq/n)=.02

thats where I'm having difficulty because i'm not sure im approaching this the correct way

Comment: $\hat{p}=.4$ and $\hat{q}=.6$, if there is no previous estimate then we have $\hat{p} = .5$ and $\hat{q} = .5$. The reason we assume $\hat{p}=\hat{q} = .5$ when we have no estimate is because this yields the highest possible $\hat{p}\cdot\hat{q}$ which is in a sense the worst case scenario requiring the largest $n$ to be $95\%$ confident.